# About the behavior of LevelsExtension when loading multiple models

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am using 'AggregatedView' to load multiple 3D model files that divide one building in the height direction.
When using 'LevelsExtension' from the viewer, only one level range of multiple models can be selected.
What rules determine the 3D model that is subject to the level range?
Also, is it possible to display and use level ranges from multiple models in the 'LevelsExtension' panel?

I thought the first model in the 'BubbleNode' list would be targeted by the level range, so I tried changing the order, but it seemed to be the same model every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `LevelsExtension` gets levels data from the first model's AEC Model Data by default, and built level ranges by levels' elevations & projection elevations.

But we can change the level data loaded in `LevelsExtension` like the below:

```js
let viewer = aggregatedView.viewer;
let model = viewer.getAllModels()[1];

let aecData = await Autodesk.Viewing.Document.getAecModelData(viewer.model.getDocumentNode();

const levelExt = viewer.getExtension('Autodesk.AEC.LevelsExtension');
levelExt.setAecModelData(aecData);
```

Here is an example showing how to build the level ranges in C#, which would help you to know the logic, and convert it to JavaScript codes.

https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-acc-locations-manager/blob/main/Autodesk/Libs/AccDataUtil.cs#L369

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will check the reference code and try it right away.

Comment: Obtain `AECModelData.json` files from each divided model (low, middle, and high), create `aecData` with integrated level information, and execute `levelExt.setAecModelData(aecData)`. Did

The 'levelExtension' panel on the viewer now displays levels from low to high, but the standards seem to be off, for example if you click on the 3rd floor, only the 15th floor model is displayed.

Is it possible to align this correctly?
If there are any problems with the methods I tried above, please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: The `levelExtension` displays the levels by the z value. The bottom one will be the level that has the minimum z value, and the top one will be the one that has the maximum z value. The problem `if you click on the 3rd floor, only the 15th floor model is displayed`, then it would depend on the floor data and the sorting order you passed to `levelExtension`.