Get the aecModelData from the manifest
I would like to know how can I get the aecModelData without needing to upload the model to the viewer. After some research in the forum, I could see that is possible to get this data from the manifest. If I have the manifest in the following format how can I proceed from here?
enter image description here

This other post's answer also has a link to a github project that finds the urn of the AecModelData from the manifest file: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77450474/4654233

sorry if I misunderstood your question, when you said you wanted to avoid uploading model to viewer, I interpreted it as you want data on backend. On the viewer side, you can refer to the link from the above comment. Let us know if the information was useful.

You upload the design file to ACC docs, not to the viewer, the viewer is for displaying the file in the browser. The manifest API gives the information about all the derivatives translated from the specified source design.
For AEC please start here: https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/aecdatamodel-beta/v1/developers_guide/API%20Essentials/usage/
You can watch the BootCamp tutorial and review this official tutorial.
EDIT:
If you already have the AEC setup, you can use aecDesignByVersionNumber query.
