Autodesk Forge DataGridPanel
I have my AutodeskForge app with NodeJs. I have several projects.
I have added the DataGridPanel.
When I switch projects, the table is not generated again.
I have this code and everything seems to be ok.
export class DataGridPanel extends Autodesk.Viewing.UI.DockingPanel {
constructor(extension, id, title, options) {
    super(extension.viewer.container, id, title, options);
    this.extension = extension;
    this.container.style.left = (options.x || 0) + 'px';
    this.container.style.top = (options.y || 0) + 'px';
    this.container.style.width = (options.width || 800) + 'px';  // Aumenta el ancho del panel
    this.container.style.height = (options.height || 400) + 'px';
    this.container.style.resize = 'none';
}

initialize() {
    this.title = this.createTitleBar(this.titleLabel || this.container.id);
    this.initializeMoveHandlers(this.title);
    this.container.appendChild(this.title);
    this.content = document.createElement('div');
    this.content.style.height = '350px';
    
    this.content.innerHTML = `<div class="datagrid-container tabulator_modern" style="position: relative; height: 350px;"></div>`;
    this.container.appendChild(this.content);
    



    // See http://tabulator.info
    this.table = new Tabulator('.datagrid-container', {
        height: '100%',
        layout: 'fitColumns',
        columns: DATAGRID_CONFIG.columns,
        groupBy: DATAGRID_CONFIG.groupBy,
        rowClick: (e, row) => DATAGRID_CONFIG.onRowClick(row.getData(), this.extension.viewer),
        cellVertAlign: 'middle',
        cellClick: (e, cell) => {
            cell.getElement().style.fontSize = '10px';  // Reduce el tamaño de la fuente de las celdas
        },
        dataLoaded: function(data) {
            this.getGroups().forEach(group => group.hide());  // Colapsa todos los grupos después de cargar los datos
        }
    });
}

update(model, dbids) {
console.log('update() called with model:', model, 'and dbids:', dbids);
model.getBulkProperties(dbids, { propFilter: DATAGRID_CONFIG.requiredProps }, (results) => {
    console.log('update DG PANEL getBulkProperties() returned results:', results);
    this.table.replaceData(results.map((result) => DATAGRID_CONFIG.createRow(result.dbId, result.name, result.properties)));
    console.log('update DG PANEL Data replaced in table');
}, (err) => {
    console.error('update DG PANEL Error in getBulkProperties():', err);
});

}
I have this console error, but I don't know if it's from this extension:
Use Document.getAecModelData(bubbleNode) instead of BubbleNode.getAecModelData(), or make sure Document.downloadAecModelData is loaded before using this API

use await as mentioned in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77443875/about-the-behavior-of-levelsextension-when-loading-multiple-models/77450474#77450474 then activate this extension.

I have tried this solution and it does not work

BTW, the above code is from which APS sample? My first guess is aps-iot-extension, if yes, which branch?

Are you still facing the issue? I want to replicate the problem if you give me the link to the GitHub code sample you're using. Our samples work fine, it's possible that the integration with different models and data could take some extra work.
